# Merge two reports to create a four column single report

Tags: c#, linq

This is related to a GameBetting related Project.

We have Two simple Lists of following Class.

```
class Gameresults
{
int userid,
double amount
}
```

The following two reports are printed on paper.

```
A) Game Winners
uid       amount
10          -
14          -
15          -

B) Game Losers
uid   amount
11          -
12          -
13          -
16          -
```

Since the columns in such report leaves space across 
the width of a Paper, we have to merge both the reports and
prepare the following report

```
Game Winners                           Game Losers
uid   Amount      uid     Amount |   uid   Amount      uid   Amount
10     -          15        -         11     -          13     -
14     -                              12     -          16     -

The above report has two columns for each report.
The Row length of WinnerReport is  totalrecords/2 , therefore two records in first
column and 1 record in next column
So first the right column is filled, rest goes to the left column
Same for LosersReport
```

the Rowlength of Winner vs Losers reports is not important.
They however must be equal (+/- 1) with respect to record count in their 
respective Lists

I made a Class to put all the records in one row, as we use printer for output of the report

```
class MergeRow
{
    int uidWinCol1; // userid,amount of winner on column 1
    double amtWinCol1;  
    int uidWinCol2;   // userid.amount of winner on column 2
    double amtWinCol2;
    int uidLosCol1;
    double amtLosCol1;
    int uidLosCol2;
    double amtLosCol2;
}
```

I need advice for the part on how to merge both lists, i presume such
a method is possible only in Linq, but any pointer or link will be helpful.

thank you

Comment: what type of application is it , winforms or web ?

Comment: it is winforms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the winnersList and losersList, each into 2 halves. Thus you would have 4 sublists.

Now you can use `FirstOrDefault` on each sublist to get an instance of`MergeRow`. In case one of the sublists become empty before the others, use `DefaultIfEmpty`, with a placeholder item.

The code would look like:

```
        var winnersList = new List<Gameresults>();
        var losersList = new List<Gameresults>();

        //Populate the winnersList and losersList


        var winnersList1 = winnersList.Take(winnersList.Count/2).ToList();
        var winnersList2 = winnersList;
        var losersList1 = losersList.Take(losersList.Count/2).ToList();
        var losersList2 = losersList;

         var allLists = new List<List<Gameresults>> {winnersList1, winnersList2, losersList1, losersList2};
        var mergeRows = new List<MergeRow>();


        while (allLists.Any(l => l.Count > 0))
        {
            var resultsInOneRow = allLists.Select(l => l.DefaultIfEmpty(new Gameresults()).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
            mergeRows.Add(GetMergeRow(resultsInOneRow));
        }
```

Your `GetMergeRow()` method would look like:

```
        private MergeRow GetMergeRow(List<Gameresults> recordsToMerge)
        {
            var mergeRow = new MergeRow();
            mergeRow.uidWinCol1 = recordsToMerge[0].userid;
            mergeRow.amtWinCol1 = recordsToMerge[0].amount;
            //... and so on
            return mergeRow;
        }
```

Comment: i like the sugestion, but this report is only a merged version of two report , except that both reports are split in two columns and are on the same page. (there is no instance of even/odd)